# how we can create android apk for python based application

Tags: android, python, opencv

I have an application in python .How can i create its Android build(apk file).
I have no idea how to do this job.Please comment if you have done this.
It is a application based on python and opencv related to the image processing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

have you heard about [kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) ?

[Here](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android) you can find git project and documentation how to do this job

[one more](https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example) sample

Comment: Is it like possible to make android apps from something like Pyglet?

Comment: "pyglet works on Windows, OS X and Linux", so it's not possible. source https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/